# Encrypt data before storing and decrypt before object mapping

Tags: encryption, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

For a security application I want to do the following:

- Each data related to a user is encrypted with this user's key (the key is unique for each user).
- The only data that are not encrypted are password (because it's already hashed, no need to crypt it on top of that), email (identifier for login) and the key (to decrypt data on server side).

The goal is to make data storage safe even if my database gets full dumped, since the attacker will have to find which algorithm(s) is used for the encryption, for each user, even if he has the key.

I'm making a RESTful API connected to this database, and I want to use Spring Data neo4j + spring Rest and Spring boot (just going to do API mapping by myself, since all my attempts to let spring generate API implementation failed).

So, the real question is How to encrypt/decrypt data in SDN's transactions? I mean I need to store data encrypted, and return it decrypted, so I need to be able to encrypt it on Java side.

If I can't do it with SDN, I'll do it using Neo4j Core API instead, just wanted to give SDN a chance since it can be really time saver.

Comment: What do you mean, the attacker would need to find which algorithm you're using? You should be using standard algorithms and keeping the key secret, not the other way around.

Comment: I explained poorly the encryption part, it's more detailed on another question I posted on security stackExchange, to solve the encryption problem. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/106965/storing-encrypted-data-readable-only-by-user-but-created-by-server